# Is there a limited number of Bitcoin wallets?

Tags: wallet, reward-schedule

Is there a theoretical upper bound on the number of possible wallets, similar to the upper bound of 21 million Bitcoins that can be generated?

Comment: Yes. ECDSA has a limited keyspace, just like we can't keep generating different RIPEMD160 hashes. But will this **ever** be a problem? No! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about Bitcoin addresses, those are considered disposable, consider this; a simple computer constantly generating Bitcoin addresses will generate all possible combinations in 69 [tredecillion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tredecillion) years.